# What file extension should I set to cache for my asp.net mvc4 application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7

I have been reading about various approaches for tuning IIS7 and one of course is caching files at the server level.  Most articles detail setting rules by file extension (css, js, asp)...

Dumb question, but what file extension (other than css, js, png) should I set for my asp.net mvc4 project, as it does not render file extensions at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

You probably just want to do output caching within your MVC app:

[Improving Performance with Output Caching (C#)](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/improving-performance-with-output-caching-cs)

Answer (score 0):

You should probably look in to the `OutputCacheAttribute`. This functionality is built right in to MVC with customization down to parameters,  timeout,  etc.

Given MVC is route driven,  using controllers and views, I don't see a file extension decision as beneficial.

Comment: Great info, thank you, mvc4 has been just good good fun to develop on thus far.

Answer (score 0):

If you are rendering your css and js files using MVC4 "Bundling" - these should already be cached for you.

You should also cache any image files you will serve.  You can do this in IIS by browsing to the folder(s) where you are storing your images, and opening "Http Response Headers" and choosing "Set Common Headers".

Lastly, as others have pointed out, judicious use of the `OutputCacheAttribute` can be used to cache the actual MVC output.  This is quite powerful, but obviously depending upon your application, some things you won't want to cache or won't be able to cache.

A good tool to check caching is the plugin for Google Chrome called "PageSpeed".  Among the many things that this checks for you, it will also let you know which resources that probably should be cached aren't being cached.

Comment: StanK, has the OutputCacheAttribute been removed for MVC4? I cannot seem to add this without error to my web.config. See this: http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/caching

Comment: The `OutputCacheAttribute` is actually added to your controller actions and works fine for MVC4.  The link you post is something different.  I'm talking about the same thing Queti Mporta gave you a link for.

Comment: From my development today, it seems that in an mvc4 project OutputCacheAttribute is only available at the controller as you recommend (works as desired, thanks), However many of the official docs give examples to set this in web.config, which does not work in an mvc4 project, thus my confusion